# Can I use DISTINCT in the OUTPUT clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, insert, distinct

I'm trying something like:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (
       Col1
      ,Col2 )
OUTPUT DISTINCT -- issue is with DISTINCT
       INSERTED.Col1
      ,@otherParameter
       INTO IdListTable
SELECT ColA
      ,ColB
      ,SUM(ImportantNumber)
FROM MyOtherTable
GROUP BY ColA, ColB
```

Except SQL doesn't want me to use `DISTINCT` in the `OUTPUT` clause. The workaround I thought of was to create a temp table for the output, then `INSERT DISTINCT` into the `IdListTable`. Any ideas on a different workaround?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replace IdListTable with a temporary table (or a table variable depending upon the number of rows) in the Output statement. Then run a second Insert statement into IdListTable from the temporary table with a Select Distinct.

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (
       Col1,
       Col2 )
OUTPUT 
       INSERTED.Col1,
       @otherParameter
       INTO #tempIdListTable
SELECT ColA,
       ColB,
       SUM(ImportantNumber)
FROM MyOtherTable
GROUP BY ColA, ColB

Insert into IdListTable
Select distinct col1, col2 from #tempIdListTable
```

Comment: This is what I'm currently doing, I was hoping I could make a single statment.

Comment: I don't believe any type of grouping or sorting is supported on the Output clause; I think you have to leave it as two separate statements.

Comment: @JeffSiver you could use ignore_dup_key on the destination table to do this in one shot

Comment: @gordy that would change the result because it would insert the duplicate records into MyTable.